# How to delete angular table array completely

Tags: angular

Currently, I'm creating a table to display some data. But there are some bugs that I can't understand why they occur. In my table, you can see I'm using one table for input and output. The main bug is after clicking add new row button and deleting the inputted data then you can see the first row of the new row outputs the deleted data and again if you click on the new row button then you can see the table new row with the earlier validation errors.

**Table with data**
[image: Table with data]

**After click on the add row button**
[image: After click on the Add row button]

**After check the validation**
[image: Check the new row validation]

**When deleting the 3rd Row**
[image: Delete the 3th Row]

**After deleting the 3rd **
[image: You can see 3th Row bug]

**After deleting the 3rd and clicking on Add Row**
[image: Last row Bug]

**Delete Method in the editing mode**

```
<td alignFrozen="right" class="flex-row-reverse p-frozen-column p-frozen-border-left align-items-start" pFrozenColumn [ngStyle]="{ width: '114px' }">
        <button [disabled]="dataSource[index].deleting" pButton type="button" (click)="handleDeleteRowClick(index)" icon="pi pi-trash"
          class="p-button-link p-button-plain p-button-rounded p-button-outlined"></button>
        <button [disabled]="!formArray[index].valid" pButton type="button" (click)="handleSaveRowClick(index)" icon="pi pi-save"
          class="p-button-link p-button-plain p-button-rounded p-button-outlined mr-1"></button>
      </td>
```

**Delete Method in the view mode**

```
<td alignFrozen="right" class="flex-row-reverse p-frozen-column p-frozen-border-left" pFrozenColumn style="width: 114px;">
          <button [disabled]="source.deleting" pButton type="button" (click)="handleDeleteRowClick(index)" icon="pi pi-trash"
          class="p-button-link p-button-plain p-button-rounded p-button-outlined"></button>
          <button pButton type="button" (click)="handleEditRowClick(index)" icon="pi pi-pencil"
            class="p-button-link p-button-plain p-button-rounded p-button-outlined mr-1"></button>
        </td>
```

**Deleting Function in .TS file**
*Here I'm using 'if' method to separate the empty row*

```
handleDeleteRowClick(index: number) {
    if(!this.dataSource[index].id){
      this.deleteRowClick.emit(index);
      this.formArray.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      this.deleteRowClick.emit(index);
    }
  }
```

**Delete method in upper "deleteRowClick" function**

```
handleDeleteRegularLogClick(index: any) {
    if(this.data.regularDatasource[index].id) {
      if(!this.data.regularDatasource[index].deleting) {
        this.dialogService.showConfirm({
          accept: () => {
            this.data.regularDatasource[index].deleting = true;
            this.deleteProjectLog('r', index)
            .then(()=>{
              this.data.regularDatasource.splice(index, 1);
              this.toastHelper.showSuccess("Deleted successfully.");
              this.getDailyTimeLogCalculation();
            })
            .catch(err=>{
              this.toastHelper.showError(err);
              this.data.regularDatasource[index].deleting = false;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
      this.data.regularDatasource.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you provide stackblitz. or something or put your full component code HTML snd ts file both?

Comment: Sorry, Deepak this is  really huge project I don't think I can provide via stackblitz . But I try @DeepakJha

Comment: what exactly are you using to creat the table

Comment: PrimeNG materials @vaira

Comment: @DamithAsanka you should be more descriptive while answering, which type of primeNG table you are using, also should have mentioned the same in the question.